# How to log in to network share via Windows 8 File Explorer

Tags: windows-8, network-shares, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exploring other windows 8 machine’s root](https://superuser.com/questions/468294/exploring-other-windows-8-machines-root)

I have two Windows 8 machines. The users on both machines use the same @live.com account. From one machine, I want to access the D:\ drive of the other machine. Normally I would just open \target\d$\ and log in with the local account on that machine (qualified by the domain or workgroup if necessary). In Windows 8, I tried using my first.last@live.com to log in, but it doesn't work. How do you do this on Windows 8?

I have tried:
first.last@live.com
first.last
first
workgroup\first.last@live.com
workgroup\first.last
workgroup\first
live.com\first.last
live.com\first

**UPDATE** I figured it out: [Enable (or work around) Administrative shares in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/492166/enable-or-work-around-administrative-shares-in-windows-8)
Administrative Shares still exist by default in Windows 8, but they are not accessible to local Administrator users (whether truly local or live.com accounts) unless you add a key in the registry. Once you do that, the correct login syntax would be `workgroup\first`

Answer (score -1):

I would try with just your 'first.last'.  Or even 'first'.  My live ID is guy@cpafafad.  I just use 'guy' or machinename\guy when I need credentials to connect to another machine.